# Use Pydantic child model to manage sets of default values for the parent model

Tags: python, inheritance, pydantic, abstract-factory

I am using pydantic to manage settings for an app that supports different datasets. Each has a set of overridable defaults, but they are different per datasets. Currently, I have all of the logic correctly implemented via validators:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class DatasetSettings(BaseModel):
    dataset_name: str 
    table_name: str

    @validator("table_name", always=True)
    def validate_table_name(cls, v, values):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return v
        if values["dataset_name"] == "DATASET_1":
            return "special_dataset_1_default_table"
        if values["dataset_name"] == "DATASET_2":
            return "special_dataset_2_default_table"
        return "default_table"

class AppSettings(BaseModel):
    dataset_settings: DatasetSettings
    app_url: str
```

This way, I get different defaults based on `dataset_name`, but the user can override them if necessary. This is the desired behavior. The trouble is that once there are more than a handful of such fields and names, it gets to be a mess to read and to maintain. It seems like inheritance/polymorphism would solve this problem but the pydantic factory logic seems too hardcoded to make it feasible, especially with nested models.

```py
class Dataset1Settings(DatasetSettings):
    dataset_name: str = "DATASET_1"
    table_name: str = "special_dataset_1_default_table"

class Dataset2Settings(DatasetSettings):
    dataset_name: str = "DATASET_2"
    table_name: str = "special_dataset_2_default_table"

def dataset_settings_factory(dataset_name, table_name=None):
    if dataset_name == "DATASET_1":
        return Dataset1Settings(dataset_name, table_name)
    if dataset_name == "DATASET_2":
        return Dataset2Settings(dataset_name, table_name)
    return DatasetSettings(dataset_name, table_name)

class AppSettings(BaseModel):
    dataset_settings: DatasetSettings
    app_url: str
```

Options I've considered:

- Create a new set of default dataset settings models, override `__init__` of `DatasetSettings`,  instantiate the subclass and copy its attributes into the parent class. Kind of clunky.
- Override `__init__` of `AppSettings` using the `dataset_settings_factory` to set the `dataset_settings` attribute of `AppSettings`. Not so good because the default behavior doesn't work in the `DatasetSettings` at all, only when instantiated as a nested model in `AppSettings`.

I was hoping `Field(default_factory=dataset_settings_factory)` would work, but the `default_factory` is only for actual defaults so it has zero args. Is there some other way to intercept the args of a particular pydantic field and use a custom factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem following the first option, as follows. Code is runnable with pydantic 1.8.2 and pydantic 1.9.1.

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class DatasetSettings(BaseModel):
    dataset_name: Optional[str] = Field(default="DATASET_1")
    table_name: Optional[str] = None

    def __init__(self, **data):
        factory_dict = {"DATASET_1": Dataset1Settings, "DATASET_2": Dataset2Settings}
        dataset_name = (
            data["dataset_name"]
            if "dataset_name" in data
            else self.__fields__["dataset_name"].default
        )
        if dataset_name in factory_dict:
            data = factory_dict[dataset_name](**data).dict()
        super().__init__(**data)


class Dataset1Settings(BaseModel):
    dataset_name: str = "DATASET_1"
    table_name: str = "special_dataset_1_default_table"


class Dataset2Settings(BaseModel):
    dataset_name: str = "DATASET_2"
    table_name: str = "special_dataset_2_default_table"


class AppSettings(BaseModel):
    dataset_settings: DatasetSettings = Field(default_factory=DatasetSettings)
    app_url: Optional[str]


app_settings = AppSettings(dataset_settings={"dataset_name": "DATASET_1"})
assert app_settings.dataset_settings.table_name == "special_dataset_1_default_table"
app_settings = AppSettings(dataset_settings={"dataset_name": "DATASET_2"})
assert app_settings.dataset_settings.table_name == "special_dataset_2_default_table"

# bonus: no args mode
app_settings = AppSettings()
assert app_settings.dataset_settings.table_name == "special_dataset_1_default_table"
```

A couple of gotchas I discovered along the way:

1. If `Dataset1Settings` inherits from `DatasetSettings`, it enters a recursive loop calling init on init ad infinitum. This could be broken with some introspection, but I opted for the duck approach.
2. The current solution destroys any validators on `DatasetSettings`. I'm sure there's a way to call the validation logic anyway but the current solution effectively sidesteps whatever class-level validation you have by only initing with `super().__init__`
3. The same thing works for `BaseSettings` objects, but you have to drag their cumbersome init args:

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        _env_file: Union[Path, str, None] = None,
        _env_file_encoding: Optional[str] = None,
        _secrets_dir: Union[Path, str, None] = None,
        **values: Any
    ):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a [Discriminated/Tagged Unions](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions).

But your solution (without looking in detail) looks fine too.